# Top 5 from two tables excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=LARGE(OneTable[Top 5 Amount],1)
```

Now I want to know how I can say.. put OneTable+TwoTable? So it works out the top 5 from both tables.

I've tried to Google this but without much luck, I hope this makes enough sense.

Comment: I am a bit confused what you are asking...  Are you saying you want the top 5 values from two tables (e.g. top 10 values), or top 5 values from both tables (e.g. 5 highest out of both), or did you want to add the tables together, then get the top 5 values from the result (or something else?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this vba code](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2011/04/21/excel-udf-combine-cell-ranges-into-a-single-range-while-eliminating-blanks/) to merge cells into a single range. Then you can apply formulas to newly create range and look for highest and/or lowest values as you would in a traditional list.